# jQuery latest library or current version library?

Tags: jquery

Im wondering why people attached jQuery current version on to their website like below

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js
```

rather than attaching the version that gets updated by it self like below

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
```

Please let me know your thoughts on this. thanks

Comment: The latter does not cache the script as it checks each time for the latest version, and using a well known source for the script that many sites use, chances are the user already has that particular script already cached from visiting another site using the same source for the script.

Comment: If a version changes, it may not be backwards compatible with your current code, and the code will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first link to Google's API is for the minified version, being only 136 bytes compared to the second links 173 bytes.

Using a CDN, the main benefit is caching. If a user has already visited a site that uses the same CDN and the same script, they will have the script already cached in the browser, but that requires that the resource is cacheable, and the "latest" version has no expires date in the header, while the link that specify the version number expires Fri, 23 Aug 2013, so in other words one of the main advantages of using a CDN for jQuery is lost when using the second link and the file is also larger. On top of that, if something changes between versions, functions that are using certain jQuery methods that are changed during a version update could break as the CDN automatically delivers the latest version.

Using the first link seems like a good idea, but in my opinion using the second link is not, and you probably would be better of just hosting the file yourself with caching enabled.

Then there's the other reasons for using a CDN:

It increases parallelism as some browsers will only download 3 or 4 files at a time from any given site.

It reduces the amount of bandwidth used by your server as you basically get free bandwidth from the CDN.

It increases the chance that the script will already be cahced, and as more sites use the large CDN networks, more users will already have the file ready in the browser without having to download it, which speeds up your site.

It ensures that the payload will be as small as possible as Google/MS/jQuery can pre-compress the file in a wide array of formats (like GZIP or DEFLATE). This makes the time-to-download very small, because it is super compressed and it isn't compressed on the fly, like many common webservers do.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. Can you please clarify "It reduces the amount of bandwidth used by your server as you basically get free bandwidth from the CDN." Thanks

Comment: The file is downloaded to the users computer from the jQuery/MS/Google CDN, and as such from their server and not your server. That means the bandwidth used for downloading jQuery will not go on your server bill if you pay for bandwith, and many "high visitor" sites do. They are basically offering you free bandwidth to download the file.

Comment: Also, be aware that the Google API just like jQuery's API has an option where you specify just `/1/` as the version number instead of `/1.8.0/` and it will get the latest version. It is actually discouraged to use this method as it will also discard the benefits of caching as it needs to get the file each time to make sure it is the latest version etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use plugins that break up when changing jQuery version - this could just mean that such plugins are outdated / not good to use, but this way you know which version you are stick with.

And google CDN is just faster, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much idea about code.jquery.com.  But Google Apis code is in on CDN (Content delivery network), which is faster to access as compared to accessing files from your local machine.

And accessing the file from CDN is always recommended.

Please refer to below documentation for more information

Yahoo Documentation : http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Google Documentation : https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/